# Working of a Autobind Decorator in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, this, typescript-decorator

Hello I am curious about the working of the decorator in Typescript for binding **'this'** to functions in Typescript.

```
function autoBind(
    target:any,
    methodName:String,
    descriptor:PropertyDescriptor
){
    console.log("Calling Decorator");
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    const adjustableDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor = {
        configurable : true,
        get(){
            console.log("Calling get");
            const boundFn = originalMethod.bind(this);
            return boundFn;
        }
    }
    return adjustableDescriptor;
}

class ProjectInput {
 constructor(){
 this.configure(); 
}
 @autoBind
    private submitHandler(event: Event){
        console.log("Calling submit handler");
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Submitting data ...");
        console.log(this.titleInputElement.value);
    }
    private configure() {
        this.element.addEventListener("submit",this.submitHandler);
    }
}
const projInput = new ProjectInput();
```

What I did :

I created a Class ProjectInput and in the constructor i am calling the configure method so that i can add EventListeners and handle user submit data and for binding 'this' so that it reference the right object.
I created a Decorator in typescript that will call automatically as soon as the class declared

Everything is fine but I want to know the behind the scenes of the decorator how it binds the this to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I came here, hoping I'd get a more thorough answer than what I'd be able to find, but at least it encouraged me to dig a little further.

Taken directly from [React & Autobinding](https://medium.com/komenco/react-autobinding-2261a1092849):

> Autobind Decorator is an NPM package which binds methods of a class to the correct instance of `this`, even when the methods are detached. The package uses `@autobind` before methods to bind `this` to the correct reference to the component's context.

```
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        /* ... */
    }

    @autobind
    addTask(task) {
        /* ... */
        this.setState({ task });
    }

    @autobind
    myMethod2(task) {
        /* ... */
        this._anotherBindedMethod(task);
    }

    render() {
        return (
             /* ... */
        ) 
    }
}
```

> his seems like a simple solution, but I'd rather not have to add a line above each individual method inside each of my React components. Not to worry, Autobind Decorator is smart enough to let us bind all methods inside a component class at once. Like so:

```
import autobind from 'autobind-decorator'

@autobind
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        /* ... */
    }

    addTask(task) {
        /* ... */
    this.setState({ task });
    }

    /* ... */
```

}

> And just like that, `this` issue is resolved.

Anyway, hope that helps. Reading it a couple times, helped me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful cause in your code getter returns a new function each time is called and this can potentially lead to memory leaks. This happen cause **`.bind` returns a new function**.

So for example if you do `.addEventListener('click', this.submitHandler)` you're adding a new function each time. `.removeEventListener('click', this.submitHandler)` will not remove nothing cause will not match any listener

You can easily test this is truth like this

```js
const projectInput = new ProjectInput(); 
projectInput.submitHandler === projectInput.submitHandler; // false
```

So an easy fix to your code could be this one

```js
function autobindFunction(
    target:any,
    methodName:String,
    descriptor:PropertyDescriptor
){
    console.log("Calling Decorator");
    if(typeof descriptor.value !== 'function') {throw new TypeError("cannot decorate prop that is not a function")}
    const bound = descriptor.value
    const adjustableDescriptor: PropertyDescriptor = {
        configurable : true,
        value: function (...args: any[]) {
            return bound.apply(this, args)
        }
    }
    return adjustableDescriptor;
}


class Test {
    @autobindFunction
    hi() {
        console.log("asd")
    }
}

const a = new Test()
console.log(a.hi === a.hi) // true
```

In this way the reference of the function is stable and the function will be always the same

Answer (score 0):

Working with `bind` method as well as `property descriptor` is mainly from vanilla JavaScript.

Lets introduce a simple example away from decorators:

***Part one: bind***

```
const person = {
name: "John",
sayHi: function() {
    console.log(this)
    return `Hi ${this.name}`
    }
}
```

If you try to call `sayHi` method as a callback function inside any other function, `this` keyword will not refer to the object anymore.

```
const originalMethod = person.sayHi
setTimeOut(originalMethod , 1000)
```

In the above code `this` will refer to the window object (assuming you run thos file on the browser). And the reason that `sayHi` method is called as a callback function.

The solution will be easy using `bind` method. The job of `bind` that it can apply a method of a certain object to another object.

```
const bindMethod = person.sayHi.bind(person)
setTimeOut(bindMethod , 2000)
```

The meaning of the above code is that as if we call the `sayHi` method from `person` object whatever even if it is a callback function.

`this` here will refer to the object itself.

***Part two: property descriptor***

Any JS object has property descriptor and you can show them through `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(person)`

The result of this statment will be an object whose keys the same as you define in the person object. Their values will be object like this `{writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true, value: ƒ}` depending on the type of property if it is a method or attribute.

You can override the values of those, as if we redefine `sayHi` method:

```
Object.defineProperty(person, "sayHi", {
   writable: true, 
   enumerable: true, 
   configurable: true,
   get() {
     console.log("Hi from get method");
     return function () {
       console.log("Hi from the return of the get method");
     };
   },
});
```

What we do here, is we just define a `getter` to return a new value of the `sayHi` method. If we try now to print `person.sayHi` it will be the function returned from the `getter` not the original function defined in the person object.

More info on `defineProperty` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

So we can use this to `bind` this. If we write:

```
const originalMethod = person.sayHi;
Object.defineProperty(person, "sayHi", {
   get() {
     return originalMethod.bind(person) // the same as originalMethod.bind(this)
   },
});
```

Now if we retry

```
setTimeOut(person.sayHi, 4000)
```

`this` will refer to the `person` object.